# Custom Control Serialization

Tags: c#, serialization, dictionary

I'm having some problems serializing and deserializing some objects in c#.

I've a custom control with some properties i want to save, defined as follows

```
[Serializable()]
public partial class customUC: UserControl, ISerializable
{
    (...)some methods here

    public customUC(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
    {
        this.att = (int)info.GetValue("att", typeof(int));
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
    {
        info.AddValue("att", this.att);
    }
}
```

And in another class, i've a Dictionary that i'm serializing as follows:

```
[Serializable()]
public partial class data: ISerializable 
{
    public Dictionary<int, customUC> states  { get; private set;}

    (...)some methods here

    public IVRDataModel(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
    {
        **this.states = (Dictionary<int,customUC>)info.GetValue("states",typeof(Dictionary<int,customUC>));**
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
        {            
            info.AddValue("states", this.states);
        }
}
```

I'm serializing the class data with a binary formatter as follows:

```
using (var stream = File.Create(path))
{
    BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    bFormatter.Serialize(stream, this);
}
```

And deserializing using:

```
Stream stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open);
BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
data d = (data)bFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
stream.Close();
```

The problem is i cant get to deserialize the items in the Dictionary. The

```
info.GetValue("states",typeof(Dictionary<int,customUC>)
```

seems to return an empty Dictionary.

Comment: Since the Dictionary implements the SerializableAttribute why dont you just use the Serializable attribute without implementating the ISerializable interface?

Comment: @gustavodidomenico i'm not sure i did understand your answer...i think i've to implement the `ISerializable` interface because i've other attributes to add to the serialization and not just the mentioned Dictionary. Thanks for your reply